# What are the semantics of Ada task priorities on Linux?

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, ada

**Background:** I'm working on porting an Ada project from Vxworks to a Linux platform. The project heavily relies on usage of Ada's dynamic task priorities.

I've done a couple experiments which have left me confused. Ada task priorities seem to have no effect on the underlying Linux priority/niceness. Two identical tasks with different priorities take equally long to complete, even when pinned to one CPU core.

**Question:** What are the semantics of Ada tasks on Linux? Why am I seeing no effect from setting task priorities?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gnat_rm/Mapping-Ada-Tasks-onto-the-Underlying-Kernel-Threads.html states "set the priority of a thread" . https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gnat_rm/Ensuring-Compliance-with-the-Real-Time-Annex.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: What are the semantics of Ada tasks on Linux? Why am I seeing no effect from setting task priorities?

The first question has bascially been answered by Shark8. I figured I'd post the answer to my second question.

**Answer:** Using Ada task priorities on Linux requires using a Linux "real time" scheduling algorithm. The default is typically `SCHED_OTHER`. `pragma Time_Slice (0.0)` or `pragma Task_Dispatching_Policy (FIFO_Within_Priorities)` will set the scheduling algorithm to `SCHED_FIFO`. This requires running the application as root.

Note: I had tried setting SCHED_FIFO manually using `chrt` on the running process, which did not work.

Details: https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/platform_specific_information.html#index-10

Answer (score 4):

I’m not up-to-date with Linux, but I remember that you could only change task priorities from the default if you ran the program as root. There may have been other conditions; getting dynamic priorities on Sparc Solaris was complicated.

The GNAT Reference Manual’s [Specialized Needs Annexes](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnat_rm/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/specialized_needs_annexes.html) section may claim that Annex D is fully implemented, and it’s certainly true that the code is present. However, 6 of the [ACATS](http://www.ada-auth.org/acats.html) tests for Annex D fail on macOS, and the ACATS maintainer has said that the Annex D tests may not pass on non-specialised operating systems (sorry, can’t find the reference).

Answer (score 3):

> I've done a couple experiments which have left me confused. Ada task
> priorities seem to have no effect on the underlying Linux
> priority/niceness. Two identical tasks with different priorities take
> equally long to complete, even when pinned to one CPU core.

This doesn't mean as much as you might imagine: any process that is above the "general noise" priority of background processes will soak up the computations needed. Also, to consider, *what is the priority of a `task` **within your program**, which is itself a process with its own priority?*

> Question: What are the semantics of Ada tasks on Linux? Why am I
> seeing no effect from setting task priorities?

Ada's task semantics are portable and should be the exact same on Windows, bare-metal, Linux, and VxWorks -- this is one of the reasons that Ada can be so portable, to the point where nontrivial programs developed for use on other systems can be run on extraordinarily different architectures (assuming no [low-level] system dependency).

As to why you're not seeing any difference, it's probably because of the above, in conjunction with the fact that we have **FAST** machines.